# Why don't java Integers point to the same memory location under if outside of Byte bounds?

Tags: java

Well this interesting problem came up today, in Java, if two `Integer`'s are initialized to the same value, Java will have them point to the same memory location (I assume to save memory).

```
Integer x = 10;
Integer y = 10;
out.println(x.equals(y) + " " + (x==y));
```

This will output `true true`. Furthermore, we can set `x` and `y` to other numbers beside 10;

```
Integer x = -128;
Integer y = -128;
out.println(x.equals(y) + " " + (x==y));
```

And

```
Integer x = 127;
Integer y = 127;
out.println(x.equals(y) + " " + (x==y));
```

And these will also output `true true`. But if we set `x` and `y` to `-129`, they no longer point to the same memory location.

```
Integer x = -129;
Integer y = -129;
out.println(x.equals(y) + " " + (x==y));
```

This outputs `true false`, a very interesting aspect. I do not know why `Integer`'s will point to different memory locations if outside of `Byte` range and I hope someone can shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, modern JVM implementations have "singleton instances" for all integers from -128 to +128, similar to internalized strings; they are simply always existent on the heap, whether you want them or not. So boxing the int 5 into an `Integer` will not return a new Integer object, but the "singleton" instance of Integer with value 5 instead. As you observed, boxing 129 will yield an *actually* new instance, thus `==` returns `false` if you do it twice. It only works for boxed values from -128 to +128 because these are singletons under the hood for efficiency reasons.

However, I'm not sure that this is part of any language or platform specification. It is simply a performance optimization, an implementation detail. Never rely on it in your code. Use `equals()` on boxed classes, never `==` even though it "appears to work".

Comment: Muchos Thank Yous!!!